# Count between two dates for each row

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400, db2-luw

I need to count [SALES] for last 12 months per each row of [selected YearMonth]. For example, if 202110 is selected, I know between 202110 and 202011 I had one sale and [HAD SALES] in front of 202110 should show 1, however, if 202008 selected and I look back the last 12 months, there is no sale and my row should show 0.

I need something like below statement without having where clause or parameter in my statement, but I'm not sure how to put it together.

```
SELECT 
    [SELECTED YEARMONTH], 
    (COUNT(SALES) FROM TABLE 
     WHERE [SELECTED YEARMONTH] BETWEEN [SELECTED PREVYEAR] AND [SELECTED YEARMONTH])
FROM 
    TABLE;
```

[image]

Comment: you can use the OLAP function (windowing) https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=expressions-olap-specification take a look at the exemple 9: Calculate the 30-day moving average for stocks ABC and XYZ during the year 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the statement below.

Note, that you should use `RANGE` and not `ROWS` inside the `OVER` clause, if there is a chance, that there is no row for some month in your table as in the example. The expression used in `ORDER BY` returns continuous enumeration for months, which is necessary for our algorithm with `RANGE`.

If there are no gaps in months, then you may use `ORDER BY YEARMONTH ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` instead.

```
SELECT 
  YEARMONTH
, SUM (SALES) OVER 
(
ORDER BY YEARMONTH / 100 * 12 + MOD (YEARMONTH, 100) 
RANGE BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW 
) AS SALES
FROM 
(
VALUES
  (202110, 1)
--, (202109, 1)
, (202108, 1)
, (202107, 1)
, (202106, 1)
, (202105, 1)
, (202104, 1)
, (202103, 1)
, (202102, 1)
, (202101, 1)
, (202012, 1)
, (202011, 1)
, (202010, 1)
, (202009, 1)
, (202008, 1)
) T (YEARMONTH, SALES)
ORDER BY YEARMONTH DESC
```

| YEARMONTH | SALES |
| --- | --- |
| 202110 | 11 |
| 202108 | 12 |
| 202107 | 12 |
| 202106 | 11 |
| 202105 | 10 |
| 202104 | 9 |
| 202103 | 8 |
| 202102 | 7 |
| 202101 | 6 |
| 202012 | 5 |
| 202011 | 4 |
| 202010 | 3 |
| 202009 | 2 |
| 202008 | 1 |

Comment: Mark, How can I thank you!!! I learned sooo much! :)